# Auto-fill using JavaScript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to fill a text-box when another text-box field is having a value. in JavaScript i face a problem ,it wont work perfectly.

First, let's see the html code for the form itself:

```
<div style="width: 145px; height: 30px; float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 3px;">
    <label>Product Segment</label><label style="color: #F00;">*</label>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget"
    style="width: 145px; height: 30px; float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 3px;">
    <input type="text" name="productsegment" id="productsegment" onkeyup="getagentids();" value="<?php echo $productsegment;?>" />
</div>
<!--Row3 end-->

<!--Row3 -->
<div style="width: 145px; height: 30px; float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 3px;">
    <label>Product Group</label><label style="color: #F00;">*</label>
</div>
<div
    style="width: 145px; height: 30px; float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 3px;">
    <input type="text" name="productgroup" id="productgroup" value="<?php echo $productgroup;?>" />
</div>
```

Jscript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var url = "productgroupautofill.php?param=";

function GetHttpObject() {
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
        return null;
    }
}
function getagentids() {
    httpobject = GetHttpObject();

    if (httpobject != null) {
        var idValue = document.getElementById("productsegment").value;
        var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random() * 99999999);
        // cache buster

        http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true); // from
        // here
        // it
        // wont
        // work
        http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
        http.send(null);

    }
}
function handleHttpResponse() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        results = http.responseText;
        alert(results);
        document.getElementById('productgroup').value = results;
    }
}            
</script>
```

productgroupautofill.php file content .

```
<?php
require_once 'Mysql.php';
$dblink = new Mysql();
$dblink->__construct();

if(strlen($param)>0)
{
    $result = mysql_query("select productgroup from productsegmentmaster where productgroup LIKE '$param%'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $agentname = $myrow["productgroup"];
            $textout .= $agentname;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $textout=" , , ,".$param;
    }
}
echo $textout;
```

Comment: Define `won't work perfectly`.

Comment: it is going into the function till the http.open state...then it s not working...:(

Comment: ... and the error message is?

Comment: no error message..it doent work further...:(

Comment: i think the http.open connection does not establish...

Comment: This is one instance where i'l certainly recommend jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = "productgroupautofill.php?param=";
var httpobject;
function GetHttpObject() {
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
        return null;
    }
}
function getagentids() {
    httpobject = GetHttpObject();

    if (httpobject != null) {
        var idValue = document.getElementById("productsegment").value;
        var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random() * 99999999);
        // cache buster

        httpobject.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true); // from
        // here
        // it
        // wont
        // work
        httpobject.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
        httpobject.send(null);

    }
}
function handleHttpResponse() {
    if (httpobject.readyState == 4) {
        results = httpobject.responseText;
        alert(results);
        document.getElementById('productgroup').value = results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...for the reply...but its working perfectly...few mistakes i made..:P...and yours is the correct one..:)

Answer (score 0):

please try with following code in **productgroupautofill.php**

```
require_once 'Mysql.php';
$dblink = new Mysql();
$dblink->__construct();
$param=$_GET['param'];
if(strlen($param)>0)
{ 
$result = mysql_query("select productgroup from productsegmentmaster where productgroup LIKE '$param%'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) 
{
 while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $agentname = $myrow["productgroup"]; 

  $textout .= $agentname; 
  } 
  } 
  else 
  { 
  $textout=" , , ,".$param; 
  } 
  } 
  echo $textout;
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `httpobject` as:

```
httpobject = GetHttpObject();
```

but then you try to use `http`:

```
http.open( ... )
```

Change your definition to this, because you use `http` throughout the code:

```
http = GetHttpObject();
```

You also might want to declare it in the global scope:

```
var url = "productgroupautofill.php?param=";
var http;
```

Comment: <body><h1>Object not found!</h1><p>    The requested URL was not found on this server.      The link on the    <a href="output.php">referring    page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of    <a href="http://localhost:81/producttypemaster.php">that page</a>    about the error.  </p><p>If you think this is a server error, please contactthe <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.</p><h2>Error 404</h2><address>  <a href="/">localhost</a><br />  <span>Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7</span></address></body></html>

Comment: My query is not executing...properly...:(

Comment: Does the PHP work alone? Try calling it from a browser, not Javascript. When the PHP is working, move on to debug the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your tectout variable outside of the loop. Try using echo inside your loop and you should see some results coming through, In fact you don't need that variable at all. Just echo $myrow["productgroup"]; if condition is true and assign ' , , , '$param to anothher variable and echo if false

Comment: is productgroupautofill.php in the same directory that the file calling it is in? also you will need to split the array after it is sent back. If there is more than one you can tell javascript that the values are split with ' , ' and it will put the values into the array